# Cache busting with Laravel mix.version() not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-mix

I noticed that mobile Chrome shows an old, cached version of my page (I tried an Incognito window, and it always returns the newest version). I tried to solve this by adding Cache-Control: must-revalidate and max-age="0" using a global middleware, this didn't work either.

Now since I'm using Laravel Mix with my Laravel app, I tried using mix.version() but this isn't working either. I checked my mix manifest file, and it looks like this:

```
{
    "/js/app.js": "/js/app.js",
    "/css/app.css": "/css/app.css"
}
```

And my Mix file looks like this.

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .version();
```

This is how I access js file in my blade layout:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

None of the mentioned solutions worked, and it's getting quite depressing. I don't want to add query string versioning myself too...

Answer (score 1):

Did you type the following to run all Mix tasks and minify output?

```
npm run prod
```

After that, view the source, and you should see...

```
<!-- Scripts -->
<script src="/js/app.js?id=f2cfb3ba93c892c12c07"></script>
```

Comment: After seeing another comment I ran npm run production and now the manifest file shows hashed paths as it should, now this may seem like a noobish question and I'm indeed one, I have a DigitalOcean production server where I hos my apps, I have NEVER ran npm run production for my laravel/vue app to work, I just use git  to clone files into /var/www/app, so... maybe I should use npm run production after pulling changes from git? can someone shed some light on this.

Comment: You can git commit the compiled assets or you can npm run prod on your production server every time you want to change the version id/cache bust.

Comment: @gabogabans Are you committing the output of npm dev? The files in public/css and public/js should be ignored in git. You can then either run npm prod on the production box or even better is to run it locally or on a build server and just copy the files onto the server (instead of using git). If you want to make use of git on the production server, consider making it a separate repo.

Comment: Running "npm run prod" on server would require having node installed on the server. It adds another layer of complexity in my opinion. I think a better option would be to run "npm run prod" locally then commit the generated asset to a new branch (named prod for example). Then from your production server, you can clone the project from the prod branch which already contains production assets.